# What's the best data structure to hold key pair values in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

What is the best way to it in R? What is the best data structure to hold the key value pairs, and what is the best way to add new key-value pairs to the final result?

Comment: Is that a `list` column or `string` in 'description'. If it is a `list`, then `df1 %>% transmute(word = cost/lengths(description), word. = description) %>% unnest`

Comment: You're going to lose item ID, which at the moment is only implicit in the line-by-line listing.

Comment: "best" depends on your goals (expected number of key/value pairs, data types, fast searching of some keys, efficient memory usage...). Can you please clarify your intention and give us a minimal reproducible example with data?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `description` column is a string we can count the number of words in each string and divide it by `cost` and then separate every word into different row using `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(cost = cost/(str_count(description, "\\w+"))) %>%
  separate_rows(description, sep = ",")

#        cost  description
#1    600.3333      purchas
#2    600.3333           2 
#3    600.3333        file 
#4    600.3333        safe 
#5    600.3333         cbp 
#6    600.3333        offic
#7  15909.0909           4 
#8  15909.0909          ea 
#9  15909.0909         4x4 
#10 15909.0909        util  
#.....
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(cost = c(3602, 175000, 17529.46, 19794.71), description = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("     4 , ea , 4x4 , util , vehicl, 2007 , v6 , volvo , dhs , cbp , cis", 
"     offic , furnitur , new , cbp , cis , offic , manzanillo, port", 
"     offic , furnitur, new , offic , balboa , port , cbp , csi", 
"     purchas, 2 , file , safe , cbp , offic"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("cost", 
"description"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the 'description' is a `list` column, create the 'word' by dividing the 'cost' by the `lengths` of 'description' and `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  transmute(cost = cost/lengths(description), word = description) %>% 
  unnest
#        cost       word
#1    600.3333    purchas
#2    600.3333          2
#3    600.3333       file
#4    600.3333       safe
#5    600.3333        cbp
#6    600.3333      offic
#7  15909.0909          4
#8  15909.0909         ea
#9  15909.0909        4x4
#...
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(cost = c(3602, 175000, 17529.46, 19794.71), description = list(
    list("purchas", "2", "file", "safe", "cbp", "offic"), list(
        "4", "ea", "4x4", "util", "vehicl", "2007", "v6", "volvo", 
        "dhs", "cbp", "cis"), list("offic", "furnitur", "new", 
        "offic", "balboa", "port", "cbp", "csi"), list("offic", 
        "furnitur", "new", "cbp", "cis", "offic", "manzanillo", 
        "port"))), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```